# How to join compound tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables (simplified below)

```
**classes**                        **locations**
[classname][locationid][time]     [id][locationname][address]
  classA         1      1pm         1   locationA     123
  classB         2      2pm         2   locationB     456
  classC         2      3pm  
  classD         1      2pm
```

I am not sure how to word this...I want to create a SELECT statement, so that I can have all of the classes grouped together by location, without duplicating the location data. If I use:

```
SELECT * FROM classes
INNER JOIN locations ON classes.locationid = locations.id
```

I end up with a result with 4 rows. How can I get a result with 2 rows? (ex locationA containing classA and classD, without getting duplicate location data)

Is this something that cannot be done in straight MySQL? If so, I can manage in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT l.locationname, group_concat(distinct c.classname)
FROM locations l
INNER JOIN classes c ON c.locationid = l.id 
group by l.locations
```

Comment: Right general solution, except backwards: he wants classes grouped by location, not locations grouped by classes.

Comment: I think juergen got it exactly right! Now I need to work this into the larger picture. Thank you so much!